# Is it possible to obtain a list of packages added via addEventTypeAutoName()

Tags: esper

I know it's possible to add Java packages via [ConfigurationOperations.addEventTypeAutoName()](http://esper.codehaus.org/esper-4.11.0/doc/api/com/espertech/esper/client/ConfigurationOperations.html#addEventTypeAutoName(java.lang.String)) but I can't seem to find a method in the API that will return all Java packages that have been added. Does an application have to keep track of package names added or is there a way of obtaining such a list?

Answer (score 0):

getEventTypeAutoNamePackages() would return that

Comment: Hi, thanks for your reply.  I don't see that method in the API docs for `ConfigurationOperations`. Is it somewhere else?